# Lenovo z470 getting hot, after 12.04 install

Tags: lenovo, temperature

When I was using Windows 7 my notebook temperature was very good, it stayed very cool. After I installed 12.04, my notebook base is hot all the time, I cannot even put my hands on it for a long time.

My notebook has a 2nd generation Intel i5 processor. I installed Jupiter and it shows **72 Degrees Celsius** constantly.

Anyone got a fix for this? I don't want to go back to windows but if I do not find any solution I will have to do it.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop, the problem is the Optimus technology, there is not exist support from Nvidia on LInux. But I fixed that problem by installing Bumblebee, from bumblee project  just following the instructions on its wiki.

This patch, software can enable or disabled the nvidia graphics and use Intel driver, It's amazing because your laptop never will be Hot again and your batery life will be better,

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Install-and-usage Wiki in General

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee Wiki for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert at this, but what I would start of by doing is installing htop, then looking at what the CPU is doing. If the cpu load is low when you are not doing anything it could be due to the graphics chip/card is under a lot of load.

```
sudo apt-get install htop
htop
```

Answer (score -1):

i have Lenovo X121 with Ubuntu 12.04. I have the same Problem but i have figured it makes a difference when you use Unity 2D. I probably save the GPU, so the Temperature goes down is well. To start Ubuntu Unity 2D, log off and click on the circle like ubuntu sign next above to the place where you enter the password, a drop down list will appear, choose unity 2D. You might also want to try out a lightweight desktop. however... i figured that temperature goes up dramatical fast when a popup buble tool tip appears, so this made me clear its the unity desktop which uses 3d enhancement which makes the cpu run hot

sry for my bad english, i am german